# Connect nodemcu with 1602 lcd without I2C

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to connect Nodemcu esp8266 and I2C 1602. I just want to show some text from esp8266 at I2C without any other sensor/hardware in between. What should be the pins' connection between the Nodemcu and I2C?
I would be very thankful if somebody please tell me the comparison of Nodemcu and Arduino pins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are a couple of examples to do this, but there is a [library](https://github.com/johnrickman/LiquidCrystal_I2C) for I2C connection of common 16x2 LCD converters like this:
[image]
Just grab the library and put it in your libraries directory and use one of the examples:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4); // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

void setup()
{
    lcd.init(); // initialize the lcd
    // Print a message to the LCD.
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print("Hello, world!");
    lcd.setCursor(2, 1);
    lcd.print("Ywrobot Arduino!");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
    lcd.print("Arduino LCM IIC 2004");
    lcd.setCursor(2, 3);
    lcd.print("Power By Ec-yuan!");
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: Dear @M. R. I have already gone through this example. But, my problem is that I want to create a connection of nodemcu and 1602 lcd **WITHOUT** the i2c device.

Comment: You can't connect it to I2C then. So you need to drive it normally with 4 DATA pins I think, is it ok for you?